# quorum-wizard Quickstart option is failing

Tags: quorum

quorum-wizard Quickstart option is failing with error.

```
Downloading dependencies...
Using cached quorum at: /Users/vivart/.quorum-wizard/bin/quorum/20.10.0/geth
Using cached tessera at: /Users/vivart/.quorum-wizard/bin/tessera/20.10.0/tessera-app.jar
Using cached cakeshop at: /Users/vivart/.quorum-wizard/bin/cakeshop/0.11.0/cakeshop.war
Building network directory...
Generating network resources locally...
Building qdata directory...
Initializing quorum...
(node:2203) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command failed: cd '/Users/vivart/network/3-nodes-quickstart' && '/Users/vivart/.quorum-wizard/bin/quorum/20.10.0/geth' --datadir 'qdata/dd1' init 'qdata/dd1/genesis.json' 2>&1
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:652:15)
    at executeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/quorum-wizard/src/utils/execUtils.js:5:10)
    at forEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/quorum-wizard/src/generators/bashHelper.js:31:37)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at initBash (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/quorum-wizard/src/generators/bashHelper.js:31:16)
    at createDirectory (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/quorum-wizard/src/index.js:128:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at generateNetwork (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/quorum-wizard/src/index.js:112:3)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:2203) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:2203) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: If you can supply more information it would help, e.g.: quorum-wizard version, operating system, the steps to reproduce the issue etc.
If you can post the question and details on Slack #technical-support channel then you'll get a faster response. (Join Slack here: http://goquorum.com/slack-inviter)

Comment: thanks @SatpalSandhu I have posted this on slack channel and got answer. 
For others, it is because my Macos version is 10.13.6 I was getting this error. I have successfully created docker version of simple network.